# .animate jquery moves to the top of the page (filterable image gallery)

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I am trying to integrate someones code in my website which is basically a filterable image gallery...but when I click on any link to filter my gallery, my page moves to the top again and loses its current position... Here is the online link to [check the problem](http://www.asiacookware.com/products_3.html).

Please check this link and send me the correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because the link's href is set to `#` which moves you to the top of the page.

In the `click` handler for those links call [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
$(".myclass").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will prevent the default action, `#`, from being executed.

Comment: Great work thanks can you give me the full code which i can just paste there...it will be very kind of you.....Chris

Comment: Okay thanks i have got it and applied it from the link you have given in your answer, Great work thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Right at the bottom of your Click trigger for the 'a', add return:false; and it will prevent the browser from jumping to the top :)